# Drag and drop in a swipe view

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using infinite Viewpager library for swipe views in my application but i want to drag a view, say button from one page to other page any clue on how to do this?

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: While using view pager, we can say to viewpager to go to particular page by viewpager.setcurrentItem

Comment: Thanks for the reply but how can i drag it to next page??

Comment: May be this link could help you: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/drag-and-drop/android-drag-and-drop-example/

Comment: Thanx,I have already implemented this kind of drag and drop.My problem is to integrate Drag and drop in swipe views